# smart way to source the same script in different files

Tags: bash

I have three scripts:

- script_main
- script_secondary
- common

The main script sources the two other scripts, while the `script_secondary` source just the common one.

I'm wondering if there is a smart way to source `common` in both script avoiding sourcing the file multiple times.

`script_seconday` needs to source the file because it can be executed standalone

I'm thinking about defining a variable like `COMMON_LIB_LOADED='y'` and then in each script doing something like:

`[[ ! -z ${COMMON_LIB_LOADED-} ]] && source common.sh`

I'm wondering if there is a better solution to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm thinking about defining a variable like COMMON_LIB_LOADED='y' and then in each script doing something like:
>
> [[ ! -z ${COMMON_LIB_LOADED-} ]] && source common.sh

Great - so just set and check the variable in the script itself.

```
# common.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n "${COMMON_LIB_LOADED-}" ]]; then
     return
fi
COMMON_LIB_LOADED=blabla_does_not_matter

... the rest of script ...
```

Yes - `return` "returns" also from a `source`d  script.